# Probability of a test showing the same result twice in a row

Tags: probability

I am studying probability at the moment and there's a question I've come across.

Let's pretend we know that the probability for a given test to show positive and the tested person to really have the problem was $0,45$. What would be the probability for the person to get $2$ positive tests in a row?

Would it be $0,45^2$?

Table with test results:

[image: test_results]

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. Yes. think about flipping coins to get two heads in a row. (The table is irrelevant - it has data you need for a harder problem than the one you asked about.)

Comment: It's hard to say, because it is unlikely the results of the tests are independent.

Comment: @awkward I'm with you. In real life, the test accuracy is probably based on a large sample with individual variations, and some of those individual variations may well be causal factors in the potentially complex causal connection between whatever is being tested for and whatever shows up when the test is performed. But sure, side-stepping the annoying fact that the world doesn't always match our mathematical idealizations, the answer the book/professor will be looking for is  $0.45^2$

Comment: @Bram28 Yes, since this is a textbook problem, very likely the student is expected to assume independence in order to keep the problem simple.  In the initial version of the question (it has been edited since then), it was not clear whether or not the question came from a textbook.  In any case, I wish textbook authors would make assumptions of independence explicit, since that assumption often fails in the Real World.

Answer (score 1):

Oh!  Now that you have added the image, things change!

You wrote:

> Let's pretend we know that the probability for a given test to show positive and the tested person to really have the problem was 0,45

Now, if we take this literally, this would mean that:

$$P(P \cap D) = 0.45$$

where $P$ is the event that the person tests positive, and $D$ as the event that the person has the disease.

But, this would not allow us to compute what you seem to be asking for, which is $P(PP|D)$, i.e. the probability of someone with a disease testing positive twice in a row.

So, before you added the table, I interpreted this as: if we take someone who has the disease, then the chances of this person testing positive for the disease is $0.45$, i.e. $$P(P|D)=0.45$$

For with that, this person testing positive twice would be $0.45^2$.

However, also that interpretation turns out to be incorrect. As the table you later added shows, it's not that the probability of a person who has the disease testing positive that is $0.45$, and it is also not the probability that this person tests positive *and* has the disease that is $0.45$. Rather, it is that the probability that the person has the disease *given* that the person tests positive is $0.45$. That is, we have that:

$$P(D|P)=0.45$$

Indeed, the table shows that:

$$P(P \cap D) = \frac{0.999}{600}$$

while

$$P(P | D) = \frac{\frac{0,999}{600}}{\frac{1}{600}}=\frac{999}{1000}$$

So, likewise, I think the question is not what the chances are that someone with the disease tests positive twice, which would be

$$P(PP|D)=\big( \frac{999}{1000}\big)^2$$

but rather: given that we have someone here who just tested positive, what is the probability for this person to test positive again? I.e. what is $P(PP|P)$?

Well, as we just saw, we know that given that this person tested positive, the probability of this person having the disease is $0.45$. Therefore, the person not having the disease is $0.55$. Hence:

$$P(PP|P) = P(P|D)\cdot P(D|P) + P(P|D^C)\cdot P(D^C|P) = \frac{999}{1000} \cdot 0.45 + \frac{1.2}{599} \cdot 0.55 \approx 0.45$$